# Number occurrences

Tags: arrays, numbers

When asked to count the number of occurrences for every integer entered between 1-100, my code won't seem to work and i can't figure out why. any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");

    int[] numbers = new int[100];

    int total = 0;


    for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (total == i)
        { 
            numbers[i] ++;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        if (numbers[i] != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(total + " occurs " + numbers[total-1] + " times ");
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You create a `Scanner` object, but then you never do anything with it. If you want to read the input, you have to write something in your program to do that.